# NSURL property with "copy" attribute. Is it leaking?

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, properties, retain

I am just cleaning up my code a little bit and I found a few lines in a function where I am not sure if they are producing memory leaks.
I would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks in advance!

In the following code the variables filepath is a NSURL and filename a NSString object defined as properties. The definition attribute is set to "copy".
Here's the code :

```
-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    if ( self == object)
        return YES;

    if (!object || ![object isKindOfClass:[self class]]) 
        return NO;

    if ( ![[[self filepath] path] isEqual:[[object filepath] path]])
        return NO;

    if (![[self filename] isEqualToString:[object filename]])
        return NO;

    if (![[self filesize] isEqualToString:[object filesize]])
        return NO;

    if (![[[self filepath ] absoluteURL] isEqual:[[object filepath] absoluteURL]])
        return NO;

    if ( !([[[self filepath ] absoluteURL ] isFileURL ] && [[[object filepath] absoluteURL ] isFileURL ]))
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

From my understanding, a property with the copy attribute would return an object with a retain count of +1. This would mean, that I should have memory leaks on every if-statement.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in your code snippet indicates a leak.

The copy attribute means that you are keeping a copy of the object with a retain count of one *when you are setting the property*. You cannot leak it simply by referencing it in your code (even via that property's accessor).

On the other hand, 'filepath' and 'filename' should be released in the -dealloc method of the object in which they are included. Failure to do that (assuming a reference-count memory mode) *will* result in leaks.

Comment: Interesting! So a setting of (readonly, copy) is absolutely useless, right? I of course release the objects in the according dealloc method. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @guitarflow Have you run your application through Instruments using the Leaks module?

Comment: I know I could do that. My application needs some further work to be runnable again ;-) so I thought asking here would be the easiest alternative. But thanks for the hint!

Comment: @guitarflow Good luck to you, and I hope you get it up and running.